# Tkinter Entry.insert() changes type from int to str

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to do a simple gui for accepting user input for further processing. It's my first time when I'm using tkinter and I've encountered a strange problem. Namely Entry.insert() changes type from int to str. Moreover first it was working alright, but then I was trying to implement something and I did couple of strong ctrl + z and now I'm not able to fix it. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from dataclasses import make_dataclass


def build_gui():
    def check_for_correct_input():
        for name, value in list(entries.items())[:-1]:
            if value.get().isdigit():
                messagebox.showwarning(
                    title='Entered wrong data',
                    message=f'Field "{name}" accepts only letters.\nInstead: "{value.get()}" was provided',
                )
                return False
            elif len(value.get()) == 0:
                messagebox.showwarning(
                    title='Input not provided.',
                    message='Please provide needed input.',
                )
                return False
        for name, value in list(entries.items())[-1:]:
            print(value.get())
            print(type(value.get()))
            if not isinstance(value.get(), int):
                messagebox.showwarning(
                    title='Entered wrong data.',
                    message=f'Field "{name}" accepts only integers.\nInstead: "{value.get()}" was provided',
                )
                return False
            elif len(value.get()) == 0:
                messagebox.showwarning(
                    title='Input not provided.',
                    message='Please provide needed input.',
                )
                return False
        return True

    # saves values to config file
    def store_values():
        if check_for_correct_input():
            for name, entry in entries.items():
                entries[name] = entry.get()
            messagebox.showinfo(
                title='Valid data provided.',
                message='Program will start working now.',
            )
            root.destroy()
            return True
        messagebox.showerror(
            title='Invalid input data.',
            message=f'Please provide valid input.',
        )

    # clears all entries
    def clear_entries():
        for entry in entries.values():
            entry.delete(0, END)

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Config for wohoho.py')
    root.geometry('1000x400')
    # Heading
    Label(root, text='Enter needed data:', font='comicsansms 13 bold', pady=15).grid(row=0, column=3)

    # Text for our form
    labels = {
        'xlsx_file_name': Label(root, text='xlsx_file_name  ', font='comicsansms 12',),
        'URLs_column': Label(root, text="URLs_column  ", font='comicsansms 12',),
        'views_column': Label(root, text='views_column  ', font='comicsansms 12',),
        'date_column': Label(root, text='date_column  ', font='comicsansms 12',),
        'starting_row': Label(root, text='starting_row  ', font='comicsansms 12',),
    }

    # Pack text for our form
    row = 1
    for label in labels.values():
        label.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky=E)
        row += 1

    # Tkinter variable for storing entries
    LabelAttributes = make_dataclass(
        'LabelAttributes', ['value', 'label_name',]
    )
    labels_values = {
        'xlsx_file_name_value': LabelAttributes(
            value='.xlsx path', label_name='xlsx_file_name',
        ),
        'URLs_column_value': LabelAttributes(
            value='L', label_name='URLs_column_value',
        ),
        'views_column_value': LabelAttributes(
            value='B', label_name='views_column_value',
        ),
        'date_column_value': LabelAttributes(
            value='D', label_name='date_column_value',
        ),
        'starting_row_value': LabelAttributes(
            value=4, label_name='starting_row_value',
        ),
    }

    entries = {}
    row = 1
    for value in labels_values.values():
        entries[value.label_name] = Entry(root, width=100)
        entries[value.label_name].grid(row=row, column=3)
        entries[value.label_name].insert(0, value.value)
        row += 1

    # Button & packing it and assigning it a command
    Button(
        text='Clear',
        command=clear_entries,
        height=2,
        width=10,
        font='comicsansms 12 bold',
        bd=3,
        ).grid(row=7, column=3
    )
    Button(
        text='Accept',
        command=store_values,
        height=2,
        width=10,
        font='comicsansms 12 bold',
        bd=3,
        ).grid(row=8, column=3
    )
    root.mainloop()

build_gui()
```

As shown in this fragment:

`starting_row_value': LabelAttributes(value=4)`

I'm setting `starting_row_value` to 4 although then it goes for validation to `check_for_correct_input()` it's type is changed from int to str. I have no idea why it is happening.

Also I think that my code is messed up. If someone would be so kind to refactor it I will be grateful. Basically I would like to:

1. Take input from user (with pre-entered suggestion as in my code).
2. Validate if input is correct. If it is correct -> store it in dict/yaml or whatever, if not ask for input once again. I was also trying to implement `while` loop which was rerunning tkinter gui if it was closed and input not stored in, but I have failed :(.

Any help will be really appreciated, because I've wasted 4 hours and I'm still in the same place.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

> Namely Entry.insert() changes type from int to str... it's type is changed from int to str. I have no idea why it is happening.

Yes, this is how the `Entry` widget has always worked. The `get` method always returns a string, and the `insert` method converts all non-string arguments into strings before inserting the data into the widget. It's up to you to convert the data to the type you want.

The tkinter documentation for `get` is simply *"Return the text."*, and the canonical tcl/tk documentation is equally straightforward: *"Returns the entry's string."*.

> Moreover first it was working alright

I don't understand what you mean by that. Calling `get` on an entry widget has always returned a string.

Comment: So I messed up something, could you please help me with refactoring my code?

Comment: @BigEd94: no, stackoverflow isn't a free coding service.